# How to handle "port widths or dimensions" errors in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I got below error when using simulink:

[image]

[image]

How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Without more context about what signal width *you* are expecting, it's impossible to tell how you should be handling that within the model. You can't just "get rid" of the errors, you need to address the problem!

Comment: You can't convert a multiplexed signal (especially of dimension 18432) into physical signals. Physical signals can't be muxed as far as I know.